# How to color leaves on `ete3` Tree? (Python 3)

Tags: python, colors, tree, etetoolkit, ete3

I just started using `ete3` and it is awesome.

**How can I color the leaves of an `ete3` Tree object using a color dictionary?** I made `"c":None` because I don't want the of `c` to show up.

I want to have better control of the tree render but I can't figure out exactly how to do it.

I saw that there are [`NodeStyle` objects](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/reference/reference_treeview.html#nodestyle) but I think this is for the actual nodes.  It looks like this [`TextFace` object](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/reference/reference_treeview.html#faces) is what I need but I don't know how to use it.  [All the examples](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial_drawing.html) are adding labels.

```
# Build Tree
tree = ete3.Tree( "((a,b),c);" )
# Leaf mapping
D_leaf_color = {"a":"r", "b":"g","c":None}
# Set up style for circular tree
ts = ete3.TreeStyle()
ts.mode = "c"
# Draw Tree
tree.render("tree_test.png", dpi=300, w=500, tree_style=ts)
```

[image]

I looked at this question but it was pretty confusing: 
[How to color tree nodes with fixed set of colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389343/how-to-color-tree-nodes-with-fixed-set-of-colors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
from ete3 import Tree, TextFace, TreeStyle

# Build Tree
tree = Tree( "((a,b),c);" )
# Leaf mapping
D_leaf_color = {"a":"red", "b":"green"}
for node in tree.traverse():
    # Hide node circles
    node.img_style['size'] = 0
    if node.is_leaf():
        color = D_leaf_color.get(node.name, None)
        if color:
            name_face = TextFace(node.name, fgcolor=color, fsize=10)
            node.add_face(name_face, column=0, position='branch-right')
# Set up style for circular tree
ts = TreeStyle()
ts.mode = "c"
ts.scale = 10
# Disable the default tip names config
ts.show_leaf_name = False
ts.show_scale = False
# Draw Tree
tree.render("tree_test.png", dpi=300, w=500, tree_style=ts)
```

[image]

Comment: `name_face = TextFace(node.name, fgcolor=color, fsize=10)` I can't change the font size on my actual image :/